# Why would a president director also needs to interview candidates?

Tags: interviewing

I have little work experiences (2 years). In my first and second company the final interviewer is always the manager of the unit i will work with. Currently I'm applying to a new company, I'm a bit surprised that my interviewers are the recruiter(HRD)-> technical lead -> the manager -> vice director -> the president director. It's a mid-class IT company. I'm just wondering why would the VP and president director also need to interview me? I assuming that this company is in crisis of engineers that even the president director needs to involve in the interview process. And I also don't even think that I'm that good that even a president director needs to find out about me because as I remember the technical test is quite hard, I skipped the challenging parts to save time. If this position is for higher position such as a manager that might be reasonable but in my case it's a junior software engineer. I hope you could help me to clarify this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I'm just wondering why would the VP and president director also need
>   to interview me?

Some executives like to keep their hand in as many details as possible. I worked for a VP like that at one point in time.

Comment: Simple and straightforward answer. Interview practices vary significantly from employer to employer. At my current place, there's a requirement that at least VP (if not C-level) needs to be present in every final-round interview - even for entry level staff answering phones in the call center.

Comment: I read once that up until just a few years ago when the company got too big for it be practical any longer, Elon Musk liked to interview every employee who came to work for SpaceX. He just wanted to know who was working for him.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm just wondering why would the VP and president director also need
>   to interview me?

There could be a number of reasons. We can't answer why this specific company does it this way. Maybe they like to meet candidates personally.

> I assuming that this company is in crisis of engineers that even the
>   president director needs to involve in the interview process.

Don't make assumptions. 9 times out of 10 they're incorrect.

Comment: Thanks. The assumption scares me at some degrees. I don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of potentially valid reasons. It could be normal company procedure or just that an executive has a special interest. Or even that they don't have anyone else available on short notice and he's replacing a manager off on leave.

Engineering it's reasonably common if an executive has an engineering background or has something specific in mind for his engineering dept.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm just wondering why would the VP and president director also need
>   to interview me?

In a vacuum those titles mean nothing. That president director can have a total number of employees in the dozens. Or the company could have 100,000 employees and 25,000 are in their division. The smaller the company the more likely that you will be a few doors down the hall with somebody with an impressive sounding title.

Even large companies sometimes distribute impressive sounding titles around. I worked with one company with tens of thousands of employees but there were multiple VP's in our building. And our building was typical. In another company of a similar size the only VP I ever met in 10+ years was the retired astronaut who did nothing, but they need an impressive title to recruit them. That VP showed up at every awards presentation and project celebration, because it made the award seem much more impressive.

In my current company of 50 employees the owner interviews everybody. will he do the same if it grows to 500? Hopefully I will still be there to find out.

Comment: Actually I have a feeling that the company currently has less employees this is why the VP and president also take a part in the interview process. The truth is, In our country finding so many public complaints about bad management practiced (especially how they treated their engineers, low pay, overtime and something like that) in IT sector is much more easy.